# Mongo Import on a Production DB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database-backups

I have a production system which is running with thousands of user profiles. These profiles were added by us at the time of launch after which users have added/updated more data into it.
Now, we are planning to add around 20K more profiles into the system. These 20K Profiles are present in our staging mongo instance.

What would be the best approach to get these profiles on Production instance considering there will be constant read/writes happening on the system? Also, we want to make sure if there is any common user than his profile should not be altered as he might have made some changes to it.

I was thinking of using mongorestore as it guaranties to insert documents and not update. What would be the risk involved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As always - test it first!

If your unhappy with mongorestore's impact on loadthen a custom python script will give you more granular control.  This will allow you to put whatever business logic and checks you need and potentially add some flood limitations.

Comment: We dont need any logic while transferring the data. We just need to copy from one instance to another.

Comment: I'd still opt for using the driver as you can set the appropriate write concern. 

Mongorestore does not wait for a response from a mongod to ensure that the MongoDB process has received or recorded the insert operation, so you wont receive any error notifications from mongod.  You could use it with the journal flag but I believe that would mean stopping the production db as well.